# should I don't use addTarget of UIButton in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, addtarget

My senior was reviewing my code and he found that I have used UIButton addTarget method like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.btnAccount.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Accounts(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
  }
```

Now he is saying that you should not use addTarget in `viewDidLoad` it will take time(kind of memory management thing I didn't get it) to load view controller but I didn't find it relevant 
that's why I am asking this question did I made some mistake by doing this should I always make actions

Comment: How does he suggest you do it then ?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't hear of that and even if it is true, you should never try to do **[premature optimization](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=premature+optimization&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)** on your app. `UIButton` is a `UIControl` object, which follows an event-listener pattern, which is often implemented with a hashmap (`NSDictionary` in Objective-C) of targets ('aka' Listeners or Observers) and it is not very time-consuming operation.

---

I *personally* prefer to setup all UI component right at the beginning:

```
lazy var btnAccount: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton

    // setup button's appearance

    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Accounts(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()
```

P.S. Please ask him about the source of the fact and let me know.

Comment: I also asked him for concrete reason but I can't get is ao that's why I have to post question